# Arduino Servo is behaving strangely

Tags: arduino-due, servo, wires

I am trying to use the [Arduino Servo](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Servo) library to drive a simple [servo](http://torqpro.com/?product=sg92r-7) and am having some difficulty getting it to even move.

Here's the setup:

[image]

And the schematic that Fritzing generated for me:

[image]

And the code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

int SERVO_SIGNAL_PIN = 9;

Servo servo;
int pos = 0;
bool GOING_UP = true;

void setup() {
    // Attach the servo and give it a few seconds to reset to the starting position.
    servo.attach(SERVO_SIGNAL_PIN);
    servo.write(0);
    delay(5000);
}

void loop() {
    if((GOING_UP && pos < 180) || pos == 0) {
        GOING_UP = true; 
    } else {
        GOING_UP = false;
    }

    int step = 1;

    if(!GOING_UP) {
        step *= -1; 
    }

    pos += step;

    servo.write(pos);
    delay(15);
}
```

When I run this, nothing happens. When I attach a multimeter and set it to the "6V" setting, I have found some strange readings:

- When I connect the red multimeter lead ("red lead") to the 5V line connecting the Arduino to the breadboard, and the black multimeter lead ("black lead") to the black GND line connecting the Arduino to the breadboard, I get readings around 5V; but...
- When I connect the red lead to the red power line going *to* the servo, and the black lead to the black GND line coming back *from* the servo, I get a voltage reading of roughly **-20V**!!!

I'm not sure what this means/implies. Is anything jumping out at anyone? Anything I can troubleshoot here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The odd voltages might suggest that the servo isn't actually (fully) connected to the Arduino. As it's a diagram of the breadboard layout, not a photo, I can't say for sure, but on some breadboards the +ve/red and -ve/black rows are sometimes split in the middle. i.e. if you were to connect the Arduino's +5v to one end of the breadboards red row, and the servo to the other end, they might not be joined (same applies for -ve/black). Just a thought; apologises in advance if I’m stating the obvious.